# Two views ontop of eachother, can't use the one behind the other

Tags: android, xml, layout

I have two views:

1. ImageButton
2. AutoCompleteTextView

that are the same dimensions and stacked ontop of eachother in a RelativeView. By default, the AutoCompleteTextView is disabled. When I click a setting, I enable the AutoCompleteTextView and disable the ImageButton. However, in both states, I can never click the ImageButton, even when it is enabled and the other is disabled. Why is this?

I am using .setEnabled()

```
          <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/pp_note_1"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"/>

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:enabled="false"
                    android:id="@+id/pp_autonote_1"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp" />

            </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what do you mean by disabling ImageButton. 
It seems like you want one to work at a given case.

Why don't you use android:visibility="gone" programmatically. imageview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: Exactly, I want one to work at a time and the other to not show. Would visibility do this for me?

Comment: When you will make the imageview.setVisibility(View.GONE), it won't be visible to user so, when user will click on AutoCompleteTextView, it will take that action. Try making one visible and other GONE as per your requirement.